# add progressbar to my webview

Tags: android, webview

I have webview from :UploadHandler class in Android 4.0.4 .

I want to add a Progress Bar to web view.

All the codes I try dont work. 
Who can help. ??!

this my  MainAvtivity.java:

```
package com.com.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        initWebView(webView);
        webView.loadUrl("http://google"); // TODO input your url

    }

    private final static Object methodInvoke(Object obj, String method, Class<?>[] parameterTypes, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Method m = obj.getClass().getMethod(method, new Class[] { boolean.class });
            m.invoke(obj, args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void initWebView(WebView webView) {

        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
        // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
        // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.clearHistory();
        webView.clearFormData();
        webView.clearCache(true);

        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);

    }

    UploadHandler mUploadHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == Controller.FILE_SELECTED) {
            // Chose a file from the file picker.
            if (mUploadHandler != null) {
                mUploadHandler.onResult(resultCode, intent);
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
        public MyWebChromeClient() {

        }

        private String getTitleFromUrl(String url) {
            String title = url;
            try {
                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                String host = urlObj.getHost();
                if (host != null && !host.isEmpty()) {
                    return urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + host;
                }
                if (url.startsWith("file:")) {
                    String fileName = urlObj.getFile();
                    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty()) {
                        return fileName;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // ignore
            }

            return title;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;
            // return super.onJsAlert(view, url, message, result);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onJsConfirm(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {

            String newTitle = getTitleFromUrl(url);

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle(newTitle).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.confirm();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    result.cancel();
                }
            }).setCancelable(false).create().show();
            return true;

            // return super.onJsConfirm(view, url, message, result);
        }

        // Android 2.x
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        // Android 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "", "filesystem");
        }

        // Android 4.1
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            mUploadHandler = new UploadHandler(new Controller());
            mUploadHandler.openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType, capture);
        }
    };

    class Controller {
        final static int FILE_SELECTED = 4;

        Activity getActivity() {
            return MainActivity.this;
        }
    }

    // copied from android-4.4.3_r1/src/com/android/browser/UploadHandler.java
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /*
     * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     */

    // package com.android.browser;
    //
    // import android.app.Activity;
    // import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    // import android.content.Intent;
    // import android.net.Uri;
    // import android.os.Environment;
    // import android.provider.MediaStore;
    // import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
    // import android.widget.Toast;
    //
    // import java.io.File;
    // import java.util.Vector;
    //
    // /**
    // * Handle the file upload callbacks from WebView here
    // */
    // public class UploadHandler {

    class UploadHandler {
        /*
         * The Object used to inform the WebView of the file to upload.
         */
        private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
        private String mCameraFilePath;
        private boolean mHandled;
        private boolean mCaughtActivityNotFoundException;
        private Controller mController;
        public UploadHandler(Controller controller) {
            mController = controller;
        }
        String getFilePath() {
            return mCameraFilePath;
        }
        boolean handled() {
            return mHandled;
        }
        void onResult(int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED && mCaughtActivityNotFoundException) {
                // Couldn't resolve an activity, we are going to try again so skip
                // this result.
                mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
                return;
            }
            Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null
                    : intent.getData();
            // As we ask the camera to save the result of the user taking
            // a picture, the camera application does not return anything other
            // than RESULT_OK. So we need to check whether the file we expected
            // was written to disk in the in the case that we
            // did not get an intent returned but did get a RESULT_OK. If it was,
            // we assume that this result has came back from the camera.
            if (result == null && intent == null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                File cameraFile = new File(mCameraFilePath);
                if (cameraFile.exists()) {
                    result = Uri.fromFile(cameraFile);
                    // Broadcast to the media scanner that we have a new photo
                    // so it will be added into the gallery for the user.
                    mController.getActivity().sendBroadcast(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, result));
                }
            }
            mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            mHandled = true;
            mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = false;
        }
        void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType, String capture) {
            final String imageMimeType = "image/*";
            final String videoMimeType = "video/*";
            final String audioMimeType = "audio/*";
            final String mediaSourceKey = "capture";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamera = "camera";
            final String mediaSourceValueFileSystem = "filesystem";
            final String mediaSourceValueCamcorder = "camcorder";
            final String mediaSourceValueMicrophone = "microphone";
            // According to the spec, media source can be 'filesystem' or 'camera' or 'camcorder'
            // or 'microphone' and the default value should be 'filesystem'.
            String mediaSource = mediaSourceValueFileSystem;
            if (mUploadMessage != null) {
                // Already a file picker operation in progress.
                return;
            }
            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Parse the accept type.
            String params[] = acceptType.split(";");
            String mimeType = params[0];
            if (capture.length() > 0) {
                mediaSource = capture;
            }
            if (capture.equals(mediaSourceValueFileSystem)) {
                // To maintain backwards compatibility with the previous implementation
                // of the media capture API, if the value of the 'capture' attribute is
                // "filesystem", we should examine the accept-type for a MIME type that
                // may specify a different capture value.
                for (String p : params) {
                    String[] keyValue = p.split("=");
                    if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                        // Process key=value parameters.
                        if (mediaSourceKey.equals(keyValue[0])) {
                            mediaSource = keyValue[1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Ensure it is not still set from a previous upload.
            mCameraFilePath = null;
            if (mimeType.equals(imageMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamera)) {
                    // Specified 'image/*' and requested the camera, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camera directly.
                    startActivity(createCameraIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'image/*', capture=filesystem, or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show a traditional picker filetered on accept type
                    // so launch an intent for both the Camera and image/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(imageMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(videoMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueCamcorder)) {
                    // Specified 'video/*' and requested the camcorder, so go ahead and launch the
                    // camcorder directly.
                    startActivity(createCamcorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'video/*', capture=filesystem or an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases we show an intent for the traditional file picker, filtered
                    // on accept type so launch an intent for both camcorder and video/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCamcorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(videoMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            } else if (mimeType.equals(audioMimeType)) {
                if (mediaSource.equals(mediaSourceValueMicrophone)) {
                    // Specified 'audio/*' and requested microphone, so go ahead and launch the sound
                    // recorder.
                    startActivity(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    return;
                } else {
                    // Specified just 'audio/*',  capture=filesystem of an invalid capture parameter.
                    // In all these cases so go ahead and launch an intent for both the sound
                    // recorder and audio/* OPENABLE.
                    Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createSoundRecorderIntent());
                    chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, createOpenableIntent(audioMimeType));
                    startActivity(chooser);
                    return;
                }
            }
            // No special handling based on the accept type was necessary, so trigger the default
            // file upload chooser.
            startActivity(createDefaultOpenableIntent());
        }
        private void startActivity(Intent intent) {
            try {
                mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                // No installed app was able to handle the intent that
                // we sent, so fallback to the default file upload control.
                try {
                    mCaughtActivityNotFoundException = true;
                    mController.getActivity().startActivityForResult(createDefaultOpenableIntent(),
                            Controller.FILE_SELECTED);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e2) {
                    // Nothing can return us a file, so file upload is effectively disabled.
                    Toast.makeText(mController.getActivity(), R.string.uploads_disabled,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
        private Intent createDefaultOpenableIntent() {
            // Create and return a chooser with the default OPENABLE
            // actions including the camera, camcorder and sound
            // recorder where available.
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("*/*");
            Intent chooser = createChooserIntent(createCameraIntent(), createCamcorderIntent(),
                    createSoundRecorderIntent());
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, i);
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createChooserIntent(Intent... intents) {
            Intent chooser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intents);
            chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE,
                    mController.getActivity().getResources()
                            .getString(R.string.choose_upload));
            return chooser;
        }
        private Intent createOpenableIntent(String type) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType(type);
            return i;
        }
        private Intent createCameraIntent() {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File externalDataDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
            File cameraDataDir = new File(externalDataDir.getAbsolutePath() +
                    File.separator + "browser-photos");
            cameraDataDir.mkdirs();
            mCameraFilePath = cameraDataDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +
                    System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(mCameraFilePath)));
            return cameraIntent;
        }
        private Intent createCamcorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
        private Intent createSoundRecorderIntent() {
            return new Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

}
```

and this my layout  Main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="fill"
    android:id="@+id/rel_webpage_whole"
    android:background="#000000"
    >

    <ProgressBar

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:max="100"
        android:background="#228b22"
        />
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_below="@id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

tnx!!! :)

Comment: Of course, that the url would be fine.

Comment: Where did you call you pogressBar to show?

Comment: i dont have progressbar yet.

Comment: i only add to main.xml, i need to add code in my java

Comment: i want the progresbar show on my top webview, tnx! :)

Comment: If It is related to web code, you should be displaying progress bar using JQuery or java script in HTML page. else if you know progress, initialize android progresss and show as it, dismiss it once done

Comment: #suneel, i dont undrstand, i need to add progressbar to this webview. its possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your layout as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressDialog"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in your code

```
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = (ProgressDialog)findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Loading");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Your Message");
    progressDialog.show();
```

once loading your webview contents are done or your expected action is done,

```
    progressDialog.dismiss();
```

If you want horizontal Progress Dialog

```
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
```

if you know progress

```
    progressDialog.setProgress(0);
    progressDialog.setMax(100);
```

and Set Progress in your thread. If you don't Know progress,

```
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
```

Comment: "inconvertible types cannot cast android.view.view to android.app.progressdialog"

Comment: anyone? can help or give another sulotion ... i want progrresbar herzional...not progressdialog..

Comment: ProgressDialog progressDialog = (ProgressDialog)findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);  // this make eror!!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize progressbar like this:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
```

This is wrong casting:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = (ProgressDialog)findViewById(R.id.progressDialog);
```

Comment: ok so , i add : ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressDialog); ...but what after ?

Answer (score 0):

Use sample code below:

```
        WebView view= new WebView(getApplicationContext());
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            ProgressDialog dialog= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());


            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.setMessage("Loading please wait");
                dialog.show();
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialog.dismiss();
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });
```

If by chance app get crashed then use "MainActivity.this" at place of getapplicationContext.
Hope this will solve your problem.

I am using your code below to show dialog:

```
         private void initWebView(WebView view, String url) {

    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
//    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setSupportZoom(true);
    // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
    // settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginState", new Class[] { PluginState.class }, new Object[] { PluginState.ON });
    // settings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    methodInvoke(settings, "setPluginsEnabled", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
    // settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });
    // settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    methodInvoke(settings, "setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs", new Class[] { boolean.class }, new Object[] { true });

    view.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    view.clearHistory();
    view.clearFormData();
    view.clearCache(true);
    view.loadUrl(url);

    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            ProgressDialog dialog= new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());

            // suppose Imageview and Webview has visibility gone by default then

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //dialog.setMessage("Loading please wait");
                //dialog.show();
                Imageview.setvisivility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //dialog.dismiss();
                 imageview.setvisibility(View.GONE);
                 view.setvisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            }
        });

    view.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
    // webView.setDownloadListener(downloadListener);

}
```

now your Onceate Method;

```
        String url="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25986941"
        WebView v= (Webview)findviewbyId(R.id.webviewid);
        initWebView(v,url);
```

Comment: its make me when i run the app... "choose browser " screen.(not open the link)

Comment: :( not work. you can send the full code whith my code?

Comment: Yes i cqn but tomorrow because  i am out of office now

Comment: My friend, 
Your answer works, but it's not what I need. I want Horizontal Progress Bar. Loading line at the top of the screen. 
I would be happy if you could help me with Progress Bar Horizontal but fit my code! 

Thanks again, you are really a genius!

Comment: I have a question, 
A friend told me to make a splash by creating - 
// LAYOUT FILE 
ImageView 
android: visibility = "visible" 
webview 
  android: visibility = "gone" 

Then Java, 
  onPageFinished do - 
  myWebView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE); 

The question is whether it is possible to hide the first loading dialog,
That it hides the Splash-photos!

Understanding what I want?

Comment: We can make visible and gone. So  you want to show webview only when page loading finished?? It can be done

Comment: webview only when page loading finished, i do . but i want show imageview(splashscreen) without progressdialog. after the page loading and the webview show the page, when i click on link its show progreesdialog ... understand ?

Comment: Wait iam going office now and i will give answer of all your queies

Comment: you are the king ! tnx ! waiting!

Comment: Maybe we can ,
Layer of the ImageView 
Will be above the ProgressDialog... Possible??

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can show progressdialog to webview and dismiss dialog when web view page loading is finished

```
      public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity {

        WebView myBrowser;
        ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapwebview); 
            myBrowser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.mybrowser);
            myBrowser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(Activity.this, "Please Wait", "Refreshing");
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (progress.isShowing()) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    } 
                }
            });
            //load saved file 

            Log.e("PAth", getFilesDir().toString());
            myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///"+getFilesDir()+"/MySampleFile.html");
            myBrowser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        }   


    }
```

Comment: tnx !! its work but the dialog proogres no stop and not hide.

Comment: its not work, the dialog not hide whene its finish to load url.

Comment: its not work, the dialog not hide whene its finish to load url.

Comment: I think its problem of url you load to webview try using simple url and check if it works